# let : $f(x): \sqrt{1-x} \ \ , x>0 , -\sqrt{1+x} \ \ , x\geq 0 $

Tags: limits

let : $$f(x): \sqrt{1-x}   \ \ : x>0 \ \ \ , \ \  -\sqrt{1+x}   \ \ : x\geq 0 $$

then :

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x^3-x)=?$$

---

my try:

$g(x)=x^3-x \to \lim_{x\to 0^-} g(x)=0$

now :

$$f(0)=-\sqrt{1+x}=-1$$

it is right ?

Comment: Note that $-1<x<0\implies f(g(x))>0.$

Comment: @mfl . why ...?

Comment: Because $x^3-x=x(x^2-1)>0$ as the product of two negative numbers and $t>0\implies f(t)=\sqrt{1-t}>0.$

Comment: Is there a typo in the definition? Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{1-x}$ for $x<0$? Otherwise $f(x)$ is not defined on all $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly.

$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 \sqrt{1-x} & x<0 \\
 -\sqrt{x+1} & x\geq 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

We are looking for $$\lim_{t\to 0^-} \, f(t^3-t)\quad(*)$$
First we have to find in which intervals $t^3-t$ is positive

$t^3-t\ge 0 \to -1\leq t\leq 0\lor t\geq 1$ and

$t^3-t< 0 \to t<-1\lor 0<t<1$

Therefore

$f(t^3-t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 \sqrt{1-t^3+t} & t<-1\lor 0<t<1 \\
 -\sqrt{1+t^3-t} & -1\leq t\leq 0\lor t\geq 1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

Now back to $(*)$

as $t<0$ the definition of the function is the second one
$$\lim_{t\to 0^-} \, f(t^3-t)=\lim_{t\to 0^-} \, \left(-\sqrt{1+t^3-t}\right)=\color{red}{-1}$$

Hope this helps